# How to use proxy in C# web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webbrowser-control

I'd like to use a proxy directly in my C# web browser control. How should I do that?

Also, I don't want to use the IE settings from registry, because it affects all the system. I want to use the proxy *only* inside my navigation to a specific website. How can I achieve that?

I tried this:

```
    currentUri = new Uri("https://www.whatismyip.com/");
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://www.whatismyip.com/");

    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("213.112.147.72:14552");
    myRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
    webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigating);
}

void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != "blank")
    {
        currentUri = new Uri(currentUri, e.Url.AbsolutePath);
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(currentUri);
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: 403 forbidden tells you, that your current credentials are either rejected by the site or by the proxy. If the proxy needs credentials to allow access, you can set them via `myProxy.Credentials`.

Comment: Try some other proxy instead. Check out [this](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/) website and tell if the problem still occurs (try other servers). But if you want to use this particular proxy then do as Adwaenyth said.

Comment: I use HMA proxy in my code

Comment: and also, how do i find out if proxy needs Credentials? because the proxy i use is public